# Create PIVOT table with MariaDB's CONNECT engine

Tags: mariadb, pivot, mariadb-10.6

Given the following base table, which implements a sort of Entity-Attribute-Value table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE dipendenti_detail (
    id_dipendente int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
    id_azienda int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    id_sede int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    revisione_documento int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    campo varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    valore varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_dipendente,id_azienda,id_sede,revisione_documento,campo)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And the following example data:

| id_dipendente | id_azienda | id_sede | revisione_documento | campo | valore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 187 | 2 | 98 | 0 | ID Ente Esterno |  |
| 187 | 2 | 98 | 0 | ID Ruolo | 1 |
| 187 | 2 | 98 | 0 | Qualifica | Amministrativo - Collaboratore di Amministrazione |
| 187 | 2 | 98 | 0 | Ruolo | Dipendente |
| 187 | 2 | 98 | 0 | test |  |
| 188 | 2 | 98 | 0 | ID Ente Esterno |  |
| 188 | 2 | 98 | 0 | ID Ruolo | 1 |
| 188 | 2 | 98 | 0 | Qualifica | Amministrativo - Collaboratore di Amministrazione |
| 188 | 2 | 98 | 0 | Ruolo | Dipendente |
| 189 | 2 | 98 | 0 | ID Ente Esterno |  |
| 189 | 2 | 98 | 0 | ID Ruolo | 1 |
| 189 | 2 | 98 | 0 | Qualifica | Amministrativo - Collaboratore di Amministrazione |
| 189 | 2 | 98 | 0 | Ruolo | Dipendente |
| 190 | 2 | 98 | 0 | ID Ente Esterno |  |
| 190 | 2 | 98 | 0 | ID Ruolo | 1 |
| 190 | 2 | 98 | 0 | Qualifica | Amministrativo - Collaboratore di Amministrazione |
| 190 | 2 | 98 | 0 | Ruolo | Dipendente |
| 191 | 2 | 98 | 0 | ID Ente Esterno |  |
| 191 | 2 | 98 | 0 | ID Ruolo | 1 |
| 191 | 2 | 98 | 0 | Qualifica | Ricercatore - Primo Ricercatore |
| 191 | 2 | 98 | 0 | Ruolo | Dipendente |
| 192 | 2 | 98 | 0 | ID Ente Esterno | 335 |
| 192 | 2 | 98 | 0 | ID Ruolo | 2 |
| 192 | 2 | 98 | 0 | Qualifica | Prof. Ordinario |
| 192 | 2 | 98 | 0 | Ruolo | Associato |
| 193 | 2 | 98 | 0 | ID Ente Esterno |  |
| 193 | 2 | 98 | 0 | ID Ruolo | 1 |
| 193 | 2 | 98 | 0 | Qualifica | Ricercatore - Ricercatore |
| 193 | 2 | 98 | 0 | Ruolo | Dipendente |
| 194 | 2 | 98 | 0 | ID Ente Esterno | 335 |
| 194 | 2 | 98 | 0 | ID Ruolo | 2 |
| 194 | 2 | 98 | 0 | Qualifica | Prof. Ordinario |
| 194 | 2 | 98 | 0 | Ruolo | Associato |
| 195 | 2 | 98 | 0 | ID Ente Esterno | 335 |
| 195 | 2 | 98 | 0 | ID Ruolo | 2 |
| 195 | 2 | 98 | 0 | Qualifica | Prof. Associato |
| 195 | 2 | 98 | 0 | Ruolo | Associato |

I tried creating a PIVOT table using the [CONNECT engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-pivot-table-type/):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE dipendenti_detail_pivot
ENGINE=CONNECT
TABLE_TYPE=PIVOT
TABNAME=dipendenti_detail
OPTION_LIST='user=connect,PivotCol=campo,FncCol=valore,Function=MAX';
```

The table is created correctly; however, when I select from it, I get an unexpected result:

| id_dipendente | id_azienda | id_sede | revisione_documento | ID Ente Esterno | ID Ruolo | Qualifica | Ruolo | test | ICE in caso di emergenza | Contatto di Emergenza | tel familiare |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 187 | 2 | 98 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 187 | 2 | 98 | 0 |  | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 187 | 2 | 98 | 0 |  |  | Amministrativo - Collaboratore di Amministrazione |  |  |  |  |  |
| 187 | 2 | 98 | 0 |  |  |  | Dipendente |  |  |  |  |
| 187 | 2 | 98 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 187 | 2 | 98 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  | 9a125ef2-24ec-4f57-97a6-76365b490bce |  |  |
| 188 | 2 | 98 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 188 | 2 | 98 | 0 |  | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 188 | 2 | 98 | 0 |  |  | Amministrativo - Collaboratore di Amministrazione |  |  |  |  |  |
| 188 | 2 | 98 | 0 |  |  |  | Dipendente |  |  |  |  |
| 188 | 2 | 98 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  | 9becc99d-3b41-4276-89fc-4dbbb1cd6b4e |  |  |

Here you can see that, while I would have expected a single for for each `(id_dipendente, id_azienda, id_sede, revisione_documento)` 4-tuple, instead I get one row for each detail field.

Did I create the PIVOT table with the wrong definition, or is it an error in the CONNECT engine itself?

I am currently using MariaDB 10.6.12 on Ubuntu 22.04.

EDIT:

Given that the original table structure does not actually need aggregation, I also tried to define the PIVOT table as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE dipendenti_detail_pivot
ENGINE=CONNECT
TABLE_TYPE=PIVOT
TABNAME=dipendenti_detail
OPTION_LIST='user=connect,PivotCol=campo,FncCol=valore,GroupBy=1';
```

But when I select from it, the result is the same.

Comment: Use conditional aggregation.

Comment: @Akina care to expand on that? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22conditional+aggregation%22

Comment: It would seem that requires to know in advance the possible values, which is not the case, so this seems not applicable to my case.

Comment: BTW, yes, now that you linked that, I recall how to do it, and the very reason why I can't do it in this case and I wanted a generic (and automatic) solution. Per the CONNECT engine docs, this is exactly the case that a PIVOT type table should solve.

Comment: Well, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66136355/10138734

Comment: Thanks for the link, I tried that and it seems to work, however let's see if someone can help me with the original question; if not, I'll use your alternative solution.